# Mobile live geolocation

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Im trying to get my Iphones live location to show on a map on my website.

Is there a way to acomplish this easily using HTML5 Geolocation or is it better to use  Google Maps Geolocation API, or some other library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use Google Maps Geolocation API in WEB APP developed with .NET C #

And it was great

Answer (score 0):

At [HyperTrack](https://hypertrack.com) we have an SDK which you can plugin to your app in as little as 3 lines of code and automatically enable location tracking in your application and view (for free) on our Dashboard. In our Sandbox mode (read: Test Mode) you can track and assign actions for up to 20 users for free as well. This mode also gives you an Action Widget that you can embed anywhere to see the activity of your user(s)/device(s).

For iOS you can visit our [iOS Integration Guide](https://docs.hypertrack.com/v3/sdks/ios/installing.html).